# Otimização e compressão avançada de imagens em servidores web sem uso de serviços externos

Tags: imagem, otimização, unix, compressão-de-imagem, processamento-de-imagens

Como fazer compressão ainda mais otimizada do que é possível conseguir com ferramentas como `ImageMagick` e `libgd` (GD) sem gerar imagem WEBP?

Alguns serviços, como https://tinypng.com/ e http://www.jpegmini.com/ prometem otimizar imagem sem perda de qualidade. Sei também que existem outras ferramentas que fazem otimizações mais complexas que levam em consideração limitações na visão humana.

Estou usando PHP 5.5 e tenho acesso root, porém qualquer ferramenta que seja compatível com *nix e possa ser executada por linha de comando, sem requerer acesso a web service externo, é bem vinda.

Comment: Se você prestar atenção na página do tinypng, eles falam de “_lossy compression_” — eles perdem qualidade _sim_, apesar do serviço ser projetado pra causar uma perda _imperceptível_ de qualidade. O que o tinypng faz são exatamente essas otimizações mais complexas que você está pensando.

Comment: Também há o `pngcrush` para png. Quais os formatos das imagens? PNG e JPEG?

Comment: Dá uma olhada neste link https://pngquant.org/ o TinyPNG usa essa biblioteca se usar ela direto no servidor não utilizará o servidor externo.

Comment: Vocês dois que fizeram comentário: se puderem dar uma resposta _mais canônica_, e relativamente documentada, mesmo que a sugestão do aplicativo sugerido tenha sido dada por outros, eu aprovo a melhor resposta, não a primeira resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara,

fazendo uma pesquisa encontrei uma resposta no stack gringo. Acho que pode te ajudar:

- `pngcrush`
- `jpegtran`

Com a opção `pngcrush -brute` eu consegui uma redução de ~20% nos `.png` e com o `jpegtran` consegui ~10% nos `.jpg`.

Answer (score 4):

beleza?

Se o que você ta precisando é comprimir imagens pra uso otimizado na web, eu recomendo a leitura deste artigos o qual **eu tive resultados satisfatórios**.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization

Baseando no fato de você não ter restrições a instalação de qualquer coisa no server, dentro deste artigo, existe uma seção: "Tools and parameter tuning", onde existe as melhores ferramentas de compressão para cada extensão de imagem.

> **Tools and parameter tuning**
>
> There is no one perfect image format, tool, or a set of optimization
>   parameters that apply to all images. For best results you will have to
>   pick the format and its settings depending on the contents of the
>   image, and its visual and other technical requirements.
>
> - gifsicle - Cria e otimiza imagens gif - http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/
> - jpegtran - Otimiza imagens JPEG - http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/
> - optipng  - Otimiza PNG ( lossless ) - http://optipng.sourceforge.net/
> - pngquant - Otimiza PNG ( lossy ) - http://pngquant.org/
>
> Don’t be afraid to experiment with parameters of each compressor. Dial
>   down the quality, see how it looks, then rinse, lather and repeat.
>   Once you’ve found a good set of settings, you can apply them to other
>   similar images on your site, but don’t assume that all images must be
>   compressed with the same settings.

Espero ter ajuadado

Comment: Jefferson, no SO links para recursos externos podem se perder. É melhor que resposta tenha no próprio corpo a resposta.

Comment: Opa, vou editar a resposta. 
Abcs